# Probability of rolling X 5 times before rolling Y

Tags: probability, permutations, dice

I played a game over the weekend in which players are required to roll a single fair die in independent trials. The objective was to roll a specific number 5 times before another specific number was rolled. If you rolled specific number X, you would get a point, but if you rolled specific number Y, your points would reset to 0. Non-X or Y numbers would not affect your score.

For example, say you had to roll five 3s before rolling a single 6. You may roll as many 1s, 2s, 4s, and 5s as you please without consequence; the only way to end the sequence is five cumulative 3s OR a single 6.

I don't know where to begin calculating the odds of this so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you ignore the four other numbers, the problem is actually equivalent to "what is the probability of getting 5 heads before a single tail when flipping a fair coin?"

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: The the number of times you rolled any particular number $X$ after $n$ rolls is binomially distributed - $\text{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{6})$. That means, that the number of times you need to roll a dice to get the number $X$, let's call it $\tau_X$ is geometrically distributed - $\tau_X \sim \text{Geom}(\frac{1}{6})$. Now, geometrical distribution has a bunch of interesting properties that you might want to investigate. There's lot of materials online to choose from. I don't want to spoil your fun (read up on memorylesness - it's awesome), but don't hesitate to ask if still you have problems.

Comment: But indeed, to answer this particular question you don't really even need to consider geometric distributions (though you should they are awesome). You can just ask "what is the probability that I will get $X$ before $Y$?", and since getting any of them in any single throw is equally likely, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$. Now, due to **memorylessness** of the process, this probability doesn't change over time (regardless of the outcomes), which makes it quite simple to find the answer to you question.